# Remove padding from text input

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the inner padding of text field? Currently when you take a normal text field in html and write something in there it'll have padding in the beginning and in the end of it. The numbers written in my text field have at most 3 digits and currently the padding pretty much covers the width of 1.5 to 2 digits and already with 2 digits (see number 10 on image) it'll get a bit dragged out.

Added image of it as well, in the first field the padded area is marked with red line.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code...

Comment: Why can you not use `padding: 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have code but

```
.my_input_class{
   padding:0;
}
```

Or, really, the size of the text box needs to be a bit larger, or you put a character limit on it

Comment: So simple and elegant, for some reason thought it applies to elemetn itself rather than it's value, well long day today.